# Importing Excel from web with openxlsx

Tags: r, excel, xlsx

I tried to read an Excel file directly from a web page using `openxlsx()`, instead of a warning I got a dataframe with the right number of columns and one row missing but seemingly random values (there are values where there shouldn't be any and the values don't correspond to the original ones). I couldn't figure a pattern which would hint at a solution.

I tried different packages (`readxl`, `xlsx`) and also tried to find the mistake by specifying the area which I want to import. Here's my code:

```
library(openxlsx)
lp <- read.xlsx("http://www.longtermproductivity.com/download/BCLDatabase_online_v2.0.xlsx", sheet = 2, skipEmptyRows = F, skipEmptyCols = F, rows=1:218, cols=1:26)
lp2 <- read.xlsx("BCLDatabase_online_v2.0.xlsx", sheet = 2)
```

All my attempts had the same result: random values in the first 50 rows where there should only be NA's except in the "year" column.

I used a workaround and simply converted the sheets into single .csv-files, which works fine. However, I frequently need to read excel files and would like to understand what's wrong in the code above.

[data](http://www.longtermproductivity.com/download/BCLDatabase_online_v2.0.xlsx) (same link as in code)

Comment: Did you try specifying the actual sheet name as `sheet="LP"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is hidden sheet at 2nd place called GDP. so try sheet name instead

```
    library(openxlsx)
    lp read.xlsx("http://www.longtermproductivity.com/download/BCLDatabase_online_v2.0.xlsx", 
sheet = "LP")
    str(lp)

'data.frame':   217 obs. of  25 variables:
 $ Year     : chr  "1800" "1801" "1802" "1803" ...
 $ ARG      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ AUS      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ AUT      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ BEL      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ BRA      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ CAN      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ CHE      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ CHL      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ DEU      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ DNK      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ESP      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ FIN      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ FRA      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ GBR      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ITA      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ JPN      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ MEX      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ NLD      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ NOR      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ NZL      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ PRT      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ SWE      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ USA      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Euro.Area: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```